# Проблема с aws amplify/cognito в реакт приложении

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth, amazon-web-services

Пробовал добавить авторизацию c Facebook через Amazon Cognito в моем реакт приложении, конфиг моего Aws Amplify выглядит так:

```js
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: config.cognito.REGION,
    UserPoolId: config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
    ClientId: config.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID
  }
});
```

Есть кнопка авторизации с Facebook, Facebook возврашает токен потом идет запрос в Cognito, вот код запроса:

```
async handleResponse(data) {
    const { email, accessToken: token, expiresIn } = data;
    const expires_at = expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime();
    const user = { email };
    const identity_id = data.userID

    console.log(identity_id)
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    try {
      const response = await Auth.federatedSignIn(
        "facebook",
        { token, expires_at },
        user
      );
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      this.props.onLogin(response);
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      this.handleError(e);
    }
  }
```

Но при авторизации выдается ошибка:

> "No Cognito Federated Identity pool provided"

Cможете подсказать как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое, что я вижу, так это то, что в объекте `user` поле `name` - обязательно, в то время как `email` и `phoneNumber` опциональны. Добавьте имя, фейсбук его возвращает в ответе вместе с токеном. Ссылка на документацию: [Federated with Auth0](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#federated-with-auth0) и код из документации:

```
Auth.federatedSignIn(
    domain, // The Auth0 Domain,
    {
        token: idToken, // The id token from Auth0
        // expires_at means the timestamp when the token provided expires,
        // here we can derive it from the expiresIn parameter provided,
        // then convert its unit from second to millisecond, and add the current timestamp
        expires_at: exp * 1000 // the expiration timestamp
    },
    { 
        // the user object, you can put whatever property you get from the Auth0
        // for exmaple:
        name, // the user name
        email, // Optional, the email address
        phoneNumber, // Optional, the phone number
    } 
)
```

Далее Auth-конфигурация `Amplify.configure`. Судя по ошибке, ему не хватает проперти `identityPoolId` - отсюда и валится ошибка. Судя из документации [Manual Setup](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#manual-setup) , в Вашем случае оно обязательно:

> ```
> // REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
> identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab',
> ```

Код из документации с описаниями:

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    // REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
    identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab',

    // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
    region: 'XX-XXXX-X',

    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Federated Identity Pool Region 
    // Required only if it's different from Amazon Cognito Region
    identityPoolRegion: 'XX-XXXX-X',

    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
    userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',

    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
    userPoolWebClientId: 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3',

    // OPTIONAL - Enforce user authentication prior to accessing AWS resources or not
    mandatorySignIn: false,

    // OPTIONAL - Configuration for cookie storage
    // Note: if the secure flag is set to true, then the cookie transmission requires a secure protocol
    cookieStorage: {
      // REQUIRED - Cookie domain (only required if cookieStorage is provided)
      domain: '.yourdomain.com',
      // OPTIONAL - Cookie path
      path: '/',
      // OPTIONAL - Cookie expiration in days
      expires: 365,
      // OPTIONAL - Cookie secure flag
      // Either true or false, indicating if the cookie transmission requires a secure protocol (https).
      secure: true
    },

    // OPTIONAL - customized storage object
    storage: new MyStorage(),

    // OPTIONAL - Manually set the authentication flow type. Default is 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
    authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH'
  }
});
```

Также, чтобы удостовериться в ошибке, достаточно найти исходный код из [Credentials](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/core/src/Credentials.ts):

```
const { region, userPoolId, identityPoolId } = this._config;
if (!identityPoolId) {
    logger.debug('No Cognito Federated Identity pool provided');
    return Promise.reject('No Cognito Federated Identity pool provided');
}
```

Здесь из конфига как раз таки достается значение `identityPoolId` и проверяется, что оно было установлено.

Comment: спасибо за ответ) да нужен был параметр,для обычной авторизации через когнито не нужен был identityPoolId и поэтому я провтыкал этот момент),еще раз спасибо